# Proving that $x^4 y^{44}-1$ is divisible by $x+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given integers $x ≠ -1$ and $y ≠ -1$ such that 
 $$\frac{x^4-1}{y+1} + \frac{y^4-1}{x+1} $$ is an integer, 
prove that $x^4y^{44} – 1$ is divisible by $x+1$.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't you already post this?

Comment: yes, i did
may i ask your help?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Notice that if two rationals $\rm\:r,s\:$ have integral $\rm\color{#0A0}{sum}$ and $\rm\color{#C00}{product}$ then they are both integers (by [Rational Root Test,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) being roots of $\rm\ (x\!-\!r)(x\!-\!s)\: =\ x^2\!-(\color{#0A0}{r\!+\!s})\,x-\color{#C00}{rs}\in\Bbb Z[x]\,).$

Thus $\rm\: x\!+\!1\mid y^4\!-1\mid y^{44}\!-1\:$ and $\rm\:x\!+\!1\mid x^4\!-1\:\Rightarrow\:x\!+\!1\mid (x^4\!-1)y^{44}\!+y^{44}\!-1 = x^4y^{44}\!-1.\ \ $ **QED**

Comment: sorry, but isn't $x≠−1$ ?
THX :)

Comment: @sannylane I made the proof more elementary by eliminating the modular arithmetic (which seems to have caused some confusion).